# Prettier labels on a BarChart

Tags: labeling, charts

How can I make better labels for the following simple `BarChart`?

```
onset1 = {8870, 73730};
peak1 = {1.3 10^8, 2 10^8};
onset2 = {2425, 5695};
peak2 = {1123, 2326};
onset3 = {88, 141};
BarChart[{onset3, onset2, peak2, onset1, peak1}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"Very long label", "Very long label", 
     "Very long label", "Very long label", "Very long label"}, {0.5, 
     1.25}], Placed[{"data1", "data2"}, Below, 
    Rotate[#, 45 Degree] &]}, PlotLabel -> "plot", Frame -> True]
```

The result is:

[image]

Labels are too close or too far from the bars and also they are long and partly superimpose to the bars themselves. How can I improve the layout of the labels?

Comment: You can use `"Very\nlong\nlabel"`.

Comment: @JimB I tried that but the labels superimpose to the smaller bars and are outside the plot for the larger ones

Comment: Use extra `\n` to get the desired position:  `"\n\nVery\nlong\nlabel"` for the high bars and `"Very\nlong\nlabel\n\n"` for the very low bars.

Comment: @JimB I didn't think about that thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think instead of scaling you can use `Above` like this  `Placed[{"Very long label", "Very long label", "Very long label","Very long label", "Very long label"}, Above]`

[image]

or with a different style like this

```
Callout[{"Very long label", "Very long label", "Very long label", 
  "Very long label", "Very long label"}, Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution:

```
peak1 = {1.3 10^8, 2 10^9};
onset2 = {2425, 5695};
peak2 = {1123, 2326};
onset3 = {88, 141};
labels = {"Very long label", "Very long label", "Very long label", 
   "Very long label", "Very long label"};
nlabels = 
  Framed[#, Background -> Blend[{Yellow, Lighter@Gray}]] &@
     Column@StringSplit[#] & /@ labels;
BarChart[{onset3, onset2, peak2, onset1, peak1}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log",
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0}, {0, 7}},
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[#, Above] &@nlabels, 
   Placed[{"data1", "data2"}, Below, Rotate[#, 45 Degree] &]}, 
 PlotLabel -> "plot", Frame -> True]
```

[image]